# Days between orderdates per Customer and first order value

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am new to DAX and have 2 questions I would like answered for a project. I am working on figuring out what the first value per customer is so what amount does the customer come in with.

In addition I would like to know what is the time between customer's orders does the customer come back to buy something after a day, week or only after a year. And if a customer comes 5 times what is the time between the orders each time.

**Data set**

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUg4L.png)

Now I tried the following but then I only get the first date back each time but then each customer gets the very first order date that exists.

```
First Order = CALCULATE(FIRSTDATE(Text[Datum].[Date]),VALUES(Text[Datum].[Date]))
```

How can I solve this two question with DAX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

1. Initial value for customer measure

```
Initial value =
-- find customers first appearance date
VAR first_date =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        FIRSTDATE ( 'Table'[Date] ),
        -- remove all filters on 'Table'[Date]
        REMOVEFILTERS ( 'Table'[Date] )
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Table'[Value] ),
        first_date
    )
```

2. First order date measure

```
First Order =
CALCULATE (
    FIRSTDATE ( 'Table'[Date] ),
    REMOVEFILTERS ( 'Table'[Date] )
)
```

3. Days passed since last visit measure

```
Days passed = 
VAR last_visit =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Table'[Date] ),
        'Table'[Date]
            -- from example expecting Customer ID & Date form unique combination, 
            -- otherwise use MAX() instead
            < SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Date] )
    )
RETURN
    DATEDIFF (
        last_visit,
        -- same here as above with SELECTEDVALUE()
        SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Date] ),
        DAY
    )
```

The result will then look like this (represented in a table visual):

[image]